# Java application to access MAILBOX using MAPI

Tags: java, mapi, james

I am trying to establish a connection between my mail server and a java program to parse the mail using protocol MAPI.. now the connection is working fine with a mock mailbox using IMAPS..but my mail server does not support MAPI..So is thr any option like JMAPI..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Java Supports POP3 and IMAP very well out of the box.

But for other protocols you can use one of the vendors found at [JavaMail API - Third Party Products](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/Third_Party.html).

I've had problems communicating with the Novell Groupwise Protocol, luckily they have a IMAP bridge I could have used instead.

The [Moonrug Exchange Connector](http://www.moonrug.com/) looks like the one you are looking for, but you will have to purchase.

[OpenMAPI](http://openmapi.org/jmapi) looks like a promising one, but it is still in development.

Comment: Java MAPI Wrapper.. is there any documentation for this ?