# Java and MAPI, what Jar is required?

Tags: java, email, mapi

I read at this thread: [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809538/how-to-send-email-using-default-email-client) , that mail clients on the local machine can be accessed via the class MAPI. What jar file do I need to be able to use this class?

Comment: Please refer this thread I think it will useful for you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618375/java-application-to-access-mailbox-using-mapi

Comment: @Markus, did you find any solution? If you got can you please share?

Answer (score 1):

If you want MAPI you could use [OpenMapi](http://openmapi.org/jmapi).

If you don't need to use MAPI, you can instead use  JavaMail API, This url has a tutorial about JavaMail API.
http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Note that JavaMail does not support MAPI [and has no plans to do so in the future](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#otherprovs).

Comment: OpenMapi is not yet available as far as my research goes and Javamail relies on a mail server. I want to send mails directly (hidden for the user) using the default mail client of the operating system running my application. So is it impossible to do this at all?

Comment: I can't understand what the "default mail client of the operating system" means?